# Iterators for different structs?

Tags: c, algorithm, design-patterns

If we have several data structures, like:

```
typedef struct {
   int par1;
   //...
   int parn1;
} struct1;

typedef struct {
   int par1;
   //...
   int parn2;
} struct2;
```

(consider in general the fields types could differ) does make any sense to abstract the iterator for the field of such structures?

Is this something actually used in practice?

What I had in mind was something like (more or less pseudocode):

```
typedef struct {
   int par1;
   //...
   int parn1;
} struct1;

typedef struct {
   int par1;
   //...
   int parn2;
} struct2;

typedef struct {
   int* iterator_ptr;
   int curr_pos;
   int n_field;
} struct_iterator;

typedef union {
   struct1 s1;
   struct2 s2;
} generic_struct;

typedef enum {
   label_struct_1,
   label_struct_2,
   n_struct
} struct_label;

struct_iterator get_iterator(generic_struct* s,struct_label label) {
   struct_iterator it;
   if(label == label_struct_1) {
      it.iterator_ptr = s->par1;
      it.curr_pos = 0;
      it.n_fields = n1;
   } else if(label == label_struct_2) {
      it.iterator_ptr = s->par1;
      it.curr_pos = 0;
      it.n_fields = n2;
   } else {
      //something else, maybe other structures to handle
   }
   return it;
 }
```

The purpose is for a code refactoring basically, I have a terrible code in C, i want to make more readable and easier to understand. I have structures like those I showed above, and different algorithms that operates on such structures, the high level algorithm is actually the same, but instead of writing a general version with spots to be specialized it has been preferred to write straight away specialized version of such algorithm. Among the steps of such algorithm there's an iteration through the structs parameters, since these structures could differs in the number of fields, but in some cases the type is the same, what I had in mind was to abstract the concept trying to implement an iterator.

I understand that probably this could sound unnecessary, however what I'm trying to achieve is the easiest way of code reuse. Something like "if u want to extend the code just implement this structures with these operations, you don't need to worry about the other things".

The examples I came up with are for sake of clarity, it's not actual code, I want to understand if the idea make sense or not.

The code is written in C, most of the concepts I'm talking about are implemented in C++, but I'm forced to use C.

A code that actually works:

File data_structure_algorithm_1.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_1_H
#define HEADER_1_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int data_1;
   int data_2;
   int data_3;
} struct_1;

void operation_1_struct_1(struct_1* s, int field) {
   if(field == 0) {
      s->data_1 = 1;
   } else if(field == 1) {
      s->data_2 = s->data_1*2 + 3;
   } else {
      s->data_3 = (s->data_1 + s->data_2)/2;
   }
}

void operation_2_struct_1(struct_1* s) {
   printf("s->data_1 = %d\n",s->data_1);
   printf("s->data_2 = %d\n",s->data_2);
   printf("s->data_3 = %d\n",s->data_3);
}
```

data_structure_algorithm_2.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_2_H
#define HEADER_2_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int data_1;
   int data_2;
   int data_3;
   int data_4;
   int data_5;
   int data_6;
} struct_2; 

void operation_1_struct_2(struct_2* s, int field) {
   if(field == 0) {
      s->data_1 = 1;
   } else if(field == 1) {
      s->data_2 = s->data_1 - 3;
   } else if(field == 2) {
      s->data_3 = (s->data_1 - s->data_2)/2;
   } else if(field == 3) {
      s->data_4 = s->data_3 - s->data_2;
   } else {
      s->data_5 = 1;
      s->data_6 = 9;
   }
}

void operation_2_struct_2(struct_2* s) {
   printf("s->data_1 = %d\n",s->data_1);
   printf("s->data_2 = %d\n",s->data_2);
   printf("s->data_3 = %d\n",s->data_3);
   printf("s->data_4 = %d\n",s->data_4);
   printf("s->data_5 = %d\n",s->data_5);
   printf("s->data_6 = %d\n",s->data_6);
}

#endif
```

iterator.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_3_H
#define HEADER_3_H
#include "data_structure_algorithm_1.h"
#include "data_structure_algorithm_2.h" 

typedef enum {
   label_struct_1,
   label_struct_2,
   n_struct } label_struct;

typedef union {
   struct_1 s1;
   struct_2 s2;
} generic_struct;

void operation_1_struct(generic_struct *s, int index, label_struct label) {
   switch(label) {
      case label_struct_1: {
         operation_1_struct_1(&(s->s1),index);
         break;
      }
      case label_struct_2: {
         operation_1_struct_2(&(s->s2),index);
         break;
      }
   }
}

void operation_2_struct(generic_struct *s, label_struct label) {
   switch(label) {
      case label_struct_1: {
         operation_2_struct_1(&(s->s1));
         break;
      }
      case label_struct_2: {
         operation_2_struct_2(&(s->s2));
         break;
      }
   }
}

typedef struct {
   int *iterator_ptr;
   int curr_pos;
   int size;
} iterator;

iterator get_iterator_s1(struct_1* s1) {
   iterator it;
   it.iterator_ptr = &(s1->data_1);
   it.curr_pos = 0;
   it.size = 3;
   return it;
}

iterator get_iterator_s2(struct_2 *s2) {
   iterator it;
   it.iterator_ptr = &(s2->data_1);
   it.curr_pos = 0;
   it.size = 6;
   return it;
}

iterator get_iterator(generic_struct* s, label_struct label) {
   switch(label) {
      case label_struct_1: {
         return get_iterator_s1(&(s->s1));
         break;
      }
      case label_struct_2: {
         return get_iterator_s2(&(s->s2));
         break;
      }
   }
}

//I don't want to modify this, because this function could be huge
void algorithm(generic_struct* s, label_struct label) {
   iterator it;

   it = get_iterator(s,label);

   while(it.curr_pos != it.size) {
      operation_1_struct(s,it.curr_pos,label);
      it.curr_pos++;
   }

   operation_2_struct(s,label);
}
```

main.c:

```
   #include "iterator.h"
   #include <string.h>
   #include <assert.h>

   int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   generic_struct strct;
   label_struct ls;
   int choice;

   assert(argc <= 2);

   if(argc == 1) {
      while(1) {
         printf("Choose the test you'd like to perform:\n");
         printf("1. struct_1;\n");
         printf("2. struct_2;\n");
         printf("Choice: "); scanf("%d",&choice);
         if(choice < 1 || choice > 2) {
            printf("Choice not valid... please try again\n");
         } else {
            if(choice == 1) ls = label_struct_1;
            else ls = label_struct_2;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   else {
      if(strcmp(argv[1],"struct_1") == 0) {
         ls = label_struct_1;
      } else if(strcmp(argv[1],"struct_2") == 0) {
         ls = label_struct_2;
      }
   }

   algorithm(&strct,ls);

   return 0;
}
```

I now I would like to let the procedure "algorithm" work on a structure with a similar behaviour I would just add a similar file "data_structure_algorithm_3.h" and update the unions, and switch statements.

Please keep in mind that this is a very minimal example (it's a kind of small framework maybe).

What i was trying to understand is weather or not such approach could has any benefits in larger context (try to imagine my function more complicated and the procedure algorithm "huge" that invokes all this similar algorithms", is it more convenient to rewrite special version of the "algorithm" or write several small functions that algorithm invokes?

I hope I made my point this time.

**Update**:

Taking inspiration from web sources, and some other answers here in SO, what do you think about the following?:

base.h:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

typedef struct base_struct base_struct;

typedef struct {
    int *ptr;
    int curr;
    int size;
} iterator;

typedef struct {
    void (*operation_1)(struct base_struct* b, int index);
    void (*operation_2)(struct base_struct* b);
    iterator (*get_iterator)(struct base_struct* b);
} vtable;

struct base_struct {
    vtable* vtbl;
};

void procedure_1(base_struct *b, int index) {
    b->vtbl->operation_1(b, index);
}

void procedure_2(base_struct *b) {
    b->vtbl->operation_2(b);
}

iterator get_iterator_proc(base_struct* b) {
    return b->vtbl->get_iterator(b);
}

void algorithm(base_struct* s) {
    iterator it;

    it = get_iterator_proc(s);

    while (it.curr != it.size) {
        procedure_1(s, it.curr);
        it.curr++;
    }

    procedure_2(s);
}


#endif /* BASE_H_ */
```

data_structure_1.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_1_H
#define HEADER_1_H
#include "base.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    base_struct base;
    int data_1;
    int data_2;
    int data_3;
} struct_1;

void operation_1_struct_1(base_struct* b, int field) {
    struct_1* s = (struct_1*)b;
    if (field == 0) {
        s->data_1 = 1;
    } else if (field == 1) {
        s->data_2 = s->data_1 * 2 + 3;
    } else {
        s->data_3 = (s->data_1 + s->data_2) / 2;
    }
}

void operation_2_struct_1(base_struct* b) {
    struct_1* s = (struct_1*)b;
    printf("s->data_1 = %d\n", s->data_1);
    printf("s->data_2 = %d\n", s->data_2);
    printf("s->data_3 = %d\n", s->data_3);
}

iterator get_iterator_struct_1(base_struct* b) {
    iterator it;
    struct_1 *s = (struct_1*)b;
    it.ptr = &(s->data_1);
    it.curr = 0;
    it.size = 3;
    return it;
}

vtable vtbl_struct_1 = {&operation_1_struct_1,&operation_2_struct_1,&get_iterator_struct_1};

void init_struct_1(struct_1* s) {
    s->base.vtbl = &vtbl_struct_1;
}

#endif /* DATA_STRUCTURE_1_H_ */
```

data_structure_2.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_2_H
#define HEADER_2_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    base_struct base;
    int data_1;
    int data_2;
    int data_3;
    int data_4;
    int data_5;
    int data_6;
} struct_2;

void operation_1_struct_2(base_struct* b, int field) {
    struct_2 *s = (struct_2*)b;
    if (field == 0) {
        s->data_1 = 1;
    } else if (field == 1) {
        s->data_2 = s->data_1 - 3;
    } else if (field == 2) {
        s->data_3 = (s->data_1 - s->data_2) / 2;
    } else if (field == 3) {
        s->data_4 = s->data_3 - s->data_2;
    } else {
        s->data_5 = 1;
        s->data_6 = 9;
    }
}

void operation_2_struct_2(base_struct* b) {
    struct_2 *s = (struct_2*)b;
    printf("s->data_1 = %d\n", s->data_1);
    printf("s->data_2 = %d\n", s->data_2);
    printf("s->data_3 = %d\n", s->data_3);
    printf("s->data_4 = %d\n", s->data_4);
    printf("s->data_5 = %d\n", s->data_5);
    printf("s->data_6 = %d\n", s->data_6);
}

iterator get_iterator_struct_2(base_struct* b) {
    iterator it;
    struct_1 *s = (struct_1*)b;
    it.ptr = &(s->data_1);
    it.curr = 0;
    it.size = 6;
    return it;
}

vtable vtbl_struct_2 = {&operation_1_struct_2,&operation_2_struct_2,&get_iterator_struct_2};

void init_struct_2(struct_2* s) {
    s->base.vtbl = &vtbl_struct_2;
}

#endif /* DATA_STRUCTURE_2_H_ */
```

main.c

```
#include "data_structure_1.h"
#include "data_structure_2.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct_1 s1;
    struct_2 s2;
    init_struct_1(&s1);
    init_struct_2(&s2);

    printf("test struct 1\n");
    algorithm((base_struct*)(&s1));

    printf("test struct 2\n");
    algorithm((base_struct*)(&s2));

    return 0;
}
```

It basically implements a small virtual table, for virtual functions. This should be good enough for my purpose right? I basically just create now different structures with they're functions table and I do not have to modify anything else, am I wrong?

Comment: Putting aside that this an abomination and in no way improves code clarity, I don't see how you propose to *use* this in a way that is well-defined behavior in C.

Comment: Instead of stating that this is an "abomination" why don't you elaborate? And I don't understand, where you see a possible way of abstraction and decoupling would you prefer to have code duplicates? I think there could be some benefits using a bit of abstraction... This is my opinion of course, and If I was sure of its effectiveness I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: I though I was pretty clear: I'd like to see how you propose to *use* this. Post a bit of example code to show your intent with this design.

Comment: I don't know how terrible your original code is, but your refactoring also looks terrible to me.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should always be very careful before consider doing any form of meta programming. It requires _lots_ of skill experience, otherwise meta programming will make the program will just turn out far worse. For example, meta programming is one of the main reasons why there exists so much broken C++ code around the world.

Comment: @EOF I'm writing some silly code showing the implementation.

Comment: @Lundin, more than meta programming is a bit of polymorfism i'm trying to implement.

Comment: Umm.... there is nothing in this code even remotely resembling polymorphism. Polymorphism in C is either implemented through function pointers or through "opaque type" where part of the struct can be hidden (like C++ `private`) or exposed to the child (like C++ `protected`). I think there are examples of both forms if you dig on SO.

Comment: @EOF have a look... It could probably look silly for small project (like in my example is probably overly redundant, however I still do think in larger projects it could be useful

Comment: For who say that the approach is not good could please explain the why...

Answer (score 2):

All of this depends on the nature of the data. It may or may not make sense to implement an abstraction layer.

If it even makes sense to make an abstraction layer, which I can't tell with the limited information about the data, it should probably be done in more elegant ways.

For example, for each struct, you can define a function which knows how to access that struct.

Then you can do something like this:

```
int get_struct1_iterator (struct1* s);
int get_struct2_iterator (struct2* s);
...

#define get_iterator(s)  _Generic((s), \
  struct1: get_struct1_iterator, \
  struct2: get_struct2_iterator)(&s)

int* i = get_iterator(my_struct);
```

Alternatively you could design something based on a standardized function format and let every struct contain a function pointer, but then you have to alter the structs.

Comment: This answer is a starting point, and the elegance issue is a point that concern me. I don't entirely get what's the difference between my proposal and yours. Can u please elaborate a bit more (some comparison and comment on my code compared to your one)?

Comment: @user8469759 This method is completely type-generic. As would the version with function pointers be, except that the type of the function pointers themselves would have to be specified. Your method however, is based on building up a "database struct" that contains all known types, and then a "super function" which knows all known access methods, and sits in a "super file" which includes everything in the project. Lots of tight coupling = very bad, hard to maintain, hard to port.

Comment: Overall, your method doesn't expand easily and doesn't allow for modular programming. With my method, the function can be provided as part of the ADT, it doesn't have to be exposed to the rest of the world.

Comment: There's an implementation of what I meant above.

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, that code has all the mentioned problems.

Comment: Can't you show me how would you adapt the example I showed with your method? I got what the problem is with my code but I still haven't entirely got your approach.

Comment: Sorry I'm realizing now I have never seen the _Generic key word before, is it a machinsm to switch at "compile time" which implementation to use? If yes what I'm looking for is a way for run-time switching (like strategy pattern).

Comment: Please, could you have a look to my update and tell me your thoughts about it?